# Execute inner shell and send/capture input/output of both shells in Go

Tags: go, command, exec

I'm trying to make a function that executes commands just like if they'd be inserted in a terminal. So if I execute (the command is to print the current shell name/path)

```
ps -p $$
bash
ps -p $$
```

I'd expect to see sh as the first shell and bash as the 2nd since I just created a new shell inside the main one --> doesn't happen and I see sh printed both times with my current code I show below.

Code:

```golang
func main() {
    var commands_list []string = []string{
        "ps -p $$",
        "bash",
        "ps -p $$",
    }
    output, err := ExecCmdSHELL(commands_list)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("-----------")
        fmt.Println(output.Exit_code)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("-----------")
        fmt.Println(output.Exit_code)
        fmt.Println("-----------")
        fmt.Println(output.Stdout_str)
        fmt.Println("-----------")
        fmt.Println(output.Stderr_str)
    }
}

func ExecCmdMainSHELL(commands_list[] string, windows_shell string, linux_shell string) (CmdOutput, error) {
    if windows_shell == "" {
        windows_shell = "powershell.exe"
    }
    if linux_shell == "" {
        linux_shell = "sh"
    }
    var shell string = ""
    if "windows" == runtime.GOOS {
        shell = windows_shell
    } else {
        shell = linux_shell
    }

    var commands_str string = ""
    for _, command := range commands_list {
        commands_str += command
        if command != "" && !strings.HasSuffix(command, "\n") {
            fmt.Println("Adding newline to command " + command)
            commands_str += "\n"
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(commands_str)

    var stdout bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer

    cmd := exec.Command(shell)
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(commands_str)
    err := cmd.Run()

    var stdout_str = strings.ReplaceAll(stdout.String(), "\r\n", "\n")
    stdout_str = strings.ReplaceAll(stdout_str, "\r", "\n")
    var stderr_str = strings.ReplaceAll(stderr.String(), "\r\n", "\n")
    stderr_str = strings.ReplaceAll(stderr_str, "\r", "\n")

    var exit_code int = 0
    if err != nil {
        var exiterr *exec.ExitError
        if errors.As(err, &exiterr) {
            exit_code = exiterr.ExitCode()
            err = nil
        } else {
            exit_code = GENERIC_ERR
        }
    }

    return CmdOutput{
        Stdout_str: stdout_str,
        Stdout:     &stdout,
        Stderr_str: stderr_str,
        Stderr:     &stderr,
        Exit_code:  exit_code,
    }, err
}
```

Output:

```
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 955719 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 955719 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
```

I expected to see `bash` on the 4th line. What's wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: in `sudo su` how are you providing root's password

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV I'm sorry, I forgot. I removed the request for the sudo password. I've edited the question, now with printing the current shell name and path (has the same issue). Should have been the first, but I forgot.